# Type mismatch error when generating random numbers

Tags: vba, excel

When I generate random numbers, I sometimes get (not always) the following error:

> Run-time error '13': type mismatch.

on line `Z = Sqr(time) * Application.NormSInv(Rnd())` (and the end of the second for loop).

Why do I get this error?

I think it has something to do with the fact that it contains `Rnd()`.

```
Sub asiancall()
'defining variables
Dim spot As Double
Dim phi As Integer
Dim rd_cont As Double
Dim rf_cont As Double
Dim lambda As Double
Dim muY As Double
Dim sigmaY As Double
Dim vol As Double

Dim implied_vol As Double
Dim spotnext As Double
Dim time As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim mean As Double
Dim payoff_mean As Double
Dim StDev As Double
Dim K As Double
Dim Egamma0 As Double
Dim mulTv As Double
Dim prod As Double
Dim U As Double
Dim Pois As Double
Dim Q As Double
Dim Z As Long
Dim gamma As Double
Dim payoff As Double
Dim payoff_sum As Double
Dim secondmoment As Double
Dim j As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim mu As Double
Dim sum1 As Double

'read input data
spot = Range("B3")
rd_cont = Range("C5")
rf_cont = Range("C4")
muY = Range("B17")
sigmaY = Range("B18")
lambda = Range("B16")
K = Range("F33")
implied_vol = Range("F35")
N = Range("F34")
vol = Range("B6")
'calculations

 sum_BS = 0
 payoff_BS = 0
 mean_BS = 0
 secondmoment_BS = 0
 For j = 1 To N
     spotnext = spot
     spotnext_BS = spot
     time = 0
     sum1 = 0
     time = 184 / (360 * 6)
     For i = 1 To 6

    '        'Merton uitvoeren
         Egamma0 = Exp(muY + sigmaY * sigmaY * 0.5) - 1
         mu = rd_cont - rf_cont
         mulTv = (mu - lambda * Egamma0 - implied_vol * implied_vol * 0.5) *   time
         sum = 0
         prod = 1
         Do While sum <= time
             U = Rnd()
             Pois = -Log(U) / lambda
             sum = sum + Pois
             Q = Application.NormInv(Rnd(), muY, sigmaY)
             gamma = Exp(Q) - 1
             prod = prod * (1 + gamma)
         Loop
         prod = prod / (1 + gamma)
         Z = Sqr(time) * Application.NormSInv(Rnd())
         spotnext = spotnext * Exp(mulTv + implied_vol * Z) * prod
         sum1 = sum1 + spotnext
     Next i
     mean = sum1 / 6
     payoff = Application.Max(mean - K, 0)
     payoff_sum = payoff_sum + payoff
     secondmoment = secondmoment + payoff * payoff
Next j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on [the community wiki answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673094/119775), a possible solution is this:

```
Function RndExcludingZero()
    Do
        RndExcludingZero = Rnd()
    Loop While RndExcludingZero = 0
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Z = Sqr(time) * Application.NormSInv(RndExcludingZero())
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rnd()` returns values >=0 and <1.

At some point it is bound to return 0. When given 0 as input in Excel, `NormSInv` returns the `#NUM!`

Excel error.* When called in VBA via `Application.NormSInv(0)`, it returns a Variant of subtype Error with value "Error 2036" (equivalent to the `#NUM!` Excel error).

Such Variant/Errors cannot be implicitly coerced to a numerical value (which is what the `*` operator expects) and thus in this case, you will get the type mismatch error.

You will only get this error when `Rnd()` happens to return 0, which is consistent with your observation that the error occurs only sometimes.

<sub>* This was first remarked by [user3964075](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964075/user3964075) in a now defunct comment to the question.</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this problem (for example by taking directly random numbers in the normal distribution) ?